# aws glue studio inner join gives error when one of data catalogue has no records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

I am new to aws glue studio. I have created two tables in the AWS glue database with partition as the current date.

I am doing inner join & left anti join to process the job.

If there is no match my glue job fails with the error

> AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "column name" among ();'

I tried custom node & select it from the collection before joining.. but no help. There are very limited options available in glue studio to play with. Let me know if there is a way in the glue studio itself to figure it out.

Comment: Could you share the code snippet that errors out? Are you checking for results before trying to process them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deactivate the job bookmarks. If one of your underlying table does not have any new data, then it will return nothing. Therefore one, or many columns cannot be resolved.
Cheers